What is “remotepairingd” and how to stop it from uploading data in macOS?
On macOS there is a process with a high amount of network activity called remotepairingd which is governed by Library/Container/com.apple.CoreDevice.remotepairingd.
I have observed the network activity for this process and often it is uploading 100s of MB of data. I do not have iCloud enabled so I am not sure what is being uploaded (although I imagine it is part of some sync process).
Does anyone have information on what this is and how it can be disabled?

I believe (no authoritative reference) it is the service managing communication between your Apple devices.  Right now one of my Macs is using it to communicate with my iPhone. It does not have high traffic.  I would be very wary about disabling if you have any other Apple devices. Sorry I can't be of more help.
